# How do I find which Dlls contain specific W32 functions?

Tags: c#, winapi, dll

My app is a WPF application and it already has code for the older type of System DPI awareness that works well in every version of windows except 8.1.  It turns out that Microsoft added a number of functions to Windows 8.1 as part of their implementation of per-monitor DPI awareness.  I need to implement code in my program to support this type of DPI awareness.

I have documentation that lists the per-monitor DPI awareness functions and what their parameters are.  I need to import those into C# and call them from my window class.  But I don't know which DLLs contain those functions!  The documentation for the `GetProcessDpiAwareness` function, for example, does not indicate which DLL it's in.

How do I find what the exports in the DLLs are?

Comment: Are you sure there's an issue with your code? It may be your VM. Are you seeing this problem in VMWare? I have a WPF window which I scale and place at a very specific location if there are multiple monitors. I observed an issue with the placement of this window when using VMWare, but could not reproduce on an actual Windows 8.1 machine or in Parallels VM.

Comment: It looks like you found a bug in their documentation, it is missing the standard "Requirements" footer that tells you which DLL to look in. Also, if you go [to the parent page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447398%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the text for `GetProcessDpiAwareness` is not a clickable link like all the rest.

Comment: Martin:  I'm not running VMWWare.  That's not it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain:  I've been working the past couple of days with the Windows 8.1 Geolocation API and I think the reason the documentation for GetProcessDpiAwareness lacks the "Requirements" footer is <b>because</b> it's a Windows 8.1 API.  All of the Windows 8.1 APIs I've looked seem to be missing that footer.  In VS 2013, you automatically get a reference to all of the .NET Framework & Windows functions.  You can do that in VS 2012, too.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22227263/which-dll-has-the-windows-devices-gelocation-namespace

Comment: The MSDN online docs seem to include the header file name and library name for functions now too. For example, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn302059.aspx for `GetProcessDpiAwareness()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right out of head, a dumb method: a binary search in `C:\Windows\System32` for `GetProcessDpiAwareness`, then studying each occurrence with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) for exports.

**This produces the result: `GetProcessDpiAwareness` is exported by `SHCore.dll`.**

One may also search the Windows SDK headers and libs, but in my case I haven't found `GetProcessDpiAwareness`, to my surprise.

Another idea, run the following from the command line prompt:

```
for %f in (%windir%\system32\*.dll) do dumpbin.exe /exports %f >>%temp%\__exports
```

Then search `%temp%\__exports` for the API.

Comment: Searching the `.h` files in the windows SDK is the easiest way I have found to do it. Just get a good full text sercher and search the sdk folder's `Include` subfolder for `*.h`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, did you manage to find `GetProcessDpiAwareness`? Perhaps, my SDK is a bit outdated.

Comment: I found it, but it is not as useful as I thought, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\ShellScalingApi.h` doesn't really say what DLL to look in. But as you found, it is `SHCore.dll` which makes sense if you look at the other functions on the website that do list which DLL they all say `SHCore.dll` too.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, could you also find it with a binary search in the `Lib` folder of the SDK?

Comment: Correct, searching `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Lib` turns up `\winv6.3\um\arm\shcore.lib`, `\winv6.3\um\x64\shcore.lib`, and `\winv6.3\um\x86\shcore.lib` (I use [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack) to do my full text searches, it will search both text and binary files for strings.)

Comment: Thank you, Noseratio & Scott Chamberlain.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been asked a while back. (Every time I Google it, this question comes up. So let me share my method.)

If anyone wants to search for functions in DLLs, there's [this tool](https://dennisbabkin.com/utilities/#WinApiSearch) that will do it for you. In case of the `GetProcessDpiAwareness` on my Windows 10 (64-bit) it is exported from `shcore.dll` like someone had already mentioned above. Here's the screenshot:

[image]

---

Although I need to preface it by saying that it would be always prudent to refer to the function's [documentation on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-getprocessdpiawareness) instead. Currently you can find it at the bottom of each page:

[image]

If you play around with the search that I showed above, you will notice that many of the system functions are exported from multiple DLLs (some of which are undocumented.) So if you just blindly go with whatever you find in a search app, you may run a risk of breaking your program in the future if Microsoft changes one of those undocumented functions. So use it only for your own research or curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

Usually functions that work with the same resources are in the same dll's. Look at another dpi function like GetDpiForMonitor and you will see it is in Shcore.dll

Edit: After you find the dll this way you can double check using dependency walker to see what functions are exported from that dll.