# What dll is needed for Windows.Devices.Geolocation?

Tags: c#, wcf, win-universal-app

I am trying to write a WCF application which will store current tablet's location to a local database. I can see that Microsoft has an API for querying current location. But I couldn't find any MSDN article specifying which dll's to add to my project in order to use the [Windows.Devices.Geolocation namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation).

Here's the [GitHub example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Geolocation) provided from Microsoft, but I can't run it because it requires Visual Studio 2015. My company does not allow migration to VS 2015, so I am still stuck with VS 2013.

Could any one please explain how I can create a WCF project using VS 2013 and query current geo location of a tablet?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which DLL has the Windows.Devices.Gelocation namespace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22227263/which-dll-has-the-windows-devices-gelocation-namespace)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the article about [Launch a Universal App from a WPF App](https://aruntalkstech.wordpress.com/2015/08/12/launch-a-universal-app-from-a-wpf-app/), we can add references to Windows Runtime dll's manually by browsing to .NET folder: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`

I am able to add `using` statements after adding references to `System.Runtime.dll`, `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll`, and most importantly, `System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll`

[image: geolocation]

Comment: Another part of the linked article solved it for me; the HintPath `<Reference Include=“Windows“>
<HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Windows.winmd</HintPath>
</Reference>`