# How to query tablet's GeoLocation within WCF application?

Tags: c#, wcf

Does Microsoft have any API for WCF applications to query a tablet's current location?

Is there any .NET third party for similar task?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What dll is needed for Windows.Devices.Geolocation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33205339/what-dll-is-needed-for-windows-devices-geolocation)

Comment: This is a watered-down version of the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33205339/what-dll-is-needed-for-windows-devices-geolocation) you posted an **hour earlier**.

Comment: But in this question, I am looking for alternative approaches.